# Random Number Generator crashes

Tags: java, android, crash

I'm making a random number generator for android and I'm new to Java. With some help, I managed to make something that should work but when I try to launch it in an emulator the app crashes. Here is the code I used:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

EditText RndNbGenNbs1, RndNbGenNbs2;
TextView RndNbGenResult;

int MinNumber;
int MaxNumber;
String Result;
Random Rnd = new Random();
String Number1;
String Number2;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RndNbGenNbs1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RndNbGenNbs1);
    RndNbGenNbs2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RndNbGenNbs2);
    RndNbGenResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RndNbGenResult);
    Number1 = RndNbGenNbs1.getText().toString();
    Number2 = RndNbGenNbs2.getText().toString();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RndNbGenBtn1);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.RndNbGenBtn1:

            MinNumber = Integer.parseInt(Number1);
            MaxNumber = Integer.parseInt(Number2);

            Rnd.nextInt(MaxNumber - MinNumber);

            Result = Rnd.toString();

            RndNbGenResult.setText(Result);
            break;


    }

}
```

}

Comment: `String Number1 = RndNbGenNbs1.getText().toString();` and `String Number2 = RndNbGenNbs2.getText().toString();` are in the initialization block of your code. Because `RndNbGenNbs1` and `RndNbGenNbs2` are not set until `onCreate()` is called, it should throw a `NullPointerException` and crash. Try debugging instead of simply running your project.

Comment: If it helps here is LogCat Log http://pastebin.com/tUuBH6qW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Log:

> ComponentInfo{com.jeepingviini.randomnumbergenerator/com.jeepingviini.randomnumbergenerator.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText

You're trying to cast an `AppCompatTextView` to `EditText`.

Check `RndNbGenNbs1`, `RndNbGenNbs2` and `RndNbGenResult`, one (or all) of them is declared as `AppCompatTextView` in xml file, while you're tryin to cast it as `EditText` in your java code.

You need to choose if you want an `EditText` or `AppCompatTextView`.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solve your problem. And open another question if you have another problem.